# Cannot remove value from array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox

I'm trying to remove an instance of 'store.state.location.locations' that should no longer should exist in my locationData array, but it seems to stay in the locationData array, even though that instance or instances are no longer being passed.

```
targetLocations() {
  // Set start search time
  this.startTime = new Date().toTimeString()

  // Set interval to update locationData every second
  setInterval(() => {
    const filteredLocations = store.state.location.locations.filter(coords => coords.socketId && coords.phoneNumber);
    const hasChanged = JSON.stringify(filteredLocations) !== JSON.stringify(this.locationData);

    if(hasChanged) {
      this.locationData = filteredLocations;

      this.map.getSource('data-source').setData({
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": this.locationData.map(this.targetElements)
      });

      // Logging phoneNumber to test 
      filteredLocations.forEach(location => console.log(location.phoneNumber+'\n'));
    }
  }, 1000);
},
```

Comment: It's possible that the instance of store.state.location.locations that you're trying to remove is being stored somewhere else in your code and is still being passed to the targetLocations() method.

Comment: @dram95 I had that thought as well, but this is most definitely the only place it exists. You can only access it from store.state.location.locations

Comment: try `this.locationData = [...filteredLocations];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shallow copy issue, the `this.locationData` is still referencing to the original `this.locationData`
You nee to clone the array into a new array (deep copy)
it can be done using spread operator

```
this.locationData = [...filteredLocations];
```

Or using Array.from

```
this.locationData = Array.from(filteredLocations);
```